# Google Search Console finds deleted products

Tags: magento-1.8, google-analytics, related-products

We have a magento 1.8.0 webshop with over a 1000 products. We always check out Google search console, and try to remove all the 404 crawl errors.
The url rewrites have been flushed and corrected, but still google finds 99 deleted products.

It says it has found it in the sitemap, but I have checked it, and I cannot find the 404 url's inside it.
I also checked the Google products export csv, but alas.

My colleague says the problem possibly lies inside the related products table in the database. Is this possible?

I found the related products sku's with the help of this tutorial:
http://www.extensions.sashas.org/blog/how-to-export-magento-cross-sell-upsell-related-products.html

But this only has the sku's and google console only has the url's.

How do I get more information? How do I know where google got the deleted product links from?

EDIT: I think I found the answer, but I'm not sure.
-I found an old google export file, and it was suddenly picked up by google somehow. 
-After I removed it, google still showed 50 crawl errors. I've searched the whole (website) filesystem with an in-text search, and I've searched the whole database for those links, but I couldn't find them in there.

Then I found this link, and it's probably why google still searches for those old links:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/30091

Comment: when you deleted those products?

Comment: These are old deleted products, from months ago, google crawled those links yesterday, after we:
flushed the url rewrites, reindexed everything and generated the google shopping export and generated the sitemap.xml

Comment: try  posting [here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)